# "Run as" android application is missing

Tags: java, android, eclipse

SDK and ADT are installed and working, but when I run some android code, the "Run As" panel is empty. I need to go to Run configuration, click on Android application, make a copy, put the name of my project on the copy and the run it. Then it run properly on the emulator. How can I add the "android application" item menu inside the run as menu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could <kbd>Right Mouse Button Click</kbd>(on activity class) > `Run As` > `Run Configurations`. Next is <kbd>Right Mouse Button Click</kbd> on `Android Application` > `New`. Now you should add your virtual emulator in `Target`. It works in my version of IDE.

Now you can use this run configurations with your own settings.

Comment: i'm not so expert with eclipse... what do you mean with "RMK"? I've googled and searched help section but i didn't find anything :(

Comment: Could you give more details regarding "Next is RMK on Android Application > New. Now you should add your virtual emulator in Target"?

Comment: Click on your `activity class`, choose `Run As` menu, then choose `Run Configurations`... Here you can adjust your emulator settings

Comment: I am having the same problem; unfortunately, *Android Application* is not among the available options in the respective dialog box any more.

Answer (score 3):

"Run as Android application" is available if u run the project (right click project name and u have that option) , and not a specific activity file ..

Answer (score 2):

Just select `Run > Run` in eclipse and select android application.The Eclipse plugin automatically creates a new run configuration for your project and then launches the Android Emulator.

Comment: when i do run > run no windows appear for selection either, how do i fix this by hand?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a bit late to be answering this, but I think my answer is better. The right click is all fine and well, but it is a bit more effort each time than my suggestion.

Right click on the toolbar and click "Customise Perspective..."
On the toolbar structure that pops up find "Launch" (On mine it's the 5th item down - it might vary)
Then you need to tick the "Run " box
After you click "OK" it should be back in the toolbar and in the menu

Comment: On my installation, I only get External Tools, no Run option,