# There is no Run menu or toolbar button in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to follow the Android Development Tutorial - this page: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

I am stuck - I cannot run the application.  The instructions say "Open one of your project's files and click Run from the toolbar."  However, there is no "Run" button on the toolbar, and there is no obvious option to choose from the "Run" dropdown on the menubar (see screenshot below).

Further down on that page, the instructions say "In Eclipse, click Android Virtual Device Manager from the toolbar."  That button is also not there!

Am I missing something really obvious?  I am on the Java perspective, and I have tried "Window -> Reset Perspective", but I am unable to run the application.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of my Eclipse]

EDIT: Under `Window -> Customize Perspective -> Menu Visibility`, I only have this - ticking Run unfortunately doesn't add anything - nor does ticking Launch under "Toolbar Visibility", when I try that I get the error `Launch cannot be made visible because it is in the unavailable null command group. Would you like to switch to the Command Group Availability tab?`.

[image: Window -> Customize Perspective]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add it like `Window` -> `CustomizePerspective` -> `Menu Visibility` -> `Run` -> `Ok`

---

or still can run your project by
Right clicking on  your project which you want to run from the project explorer and select `Run as` and then `Android application`....T daaa...

[image]

If still the problem is there check

- [The "Run As -> Android Application" is no longer an option in my Eclipse Run Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857870/the-run-as-android-application-is-no-longer-an-option-in-my-eclipse-run-con)
- ["Run as" android application is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713210/run-as-android-application-is-missing)

Comment: That's great... and it does work, but I don't suppose you know how to get the toolbar like you have in the picture?  I would really like to have it so that my Eclipse matches the tutorial exactly :)

Comment: Why not? go to Window --> CustomizePerspective --> **Menu Visibility** --> run --> Ok......and you go

Comment: Cheers, unfortunately, that doesn't do anything.  I added a screenshot of my Menu Visibility above - I think it is missing a bunch of options by the sounds of it.  I think I will follow the advice in your linked questions and just do a reinstall of eclipse.

Comment: I'll give you the accepted answer because I can at least run my application!

Answer (score 3):

`Window` -> `Customize Perspective` -> `Toolbar Visibility` -> tick `Launch` -> Press ok

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately when I try that, I get "Launch cannot be made visible because it is in the unavailable null command group.  Would you like to switch to the Command Group Availability tab?"  And on that latter tab, Launch is already ticked.

Comment: Window -> CustomizePerspective -> **Menu Visibility** -> Launch -> Ok

Comment: @Butterflow - unfortunately, there's no Launch category under Menu Visibility.  Just File, Edit, Navigate, Project, Run, Window and Help.  Under Run, there is only Breakpoint Types.

Comment: maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757085/eclipse-annoyances-debug-and-launch-toolbars-unavailable

Comment: oh i mean to say **run** on the place of **launch**

Answer (score 1):

Window -- > Open Perspective --> Java

Answer (score 1):

If the entire toolbar is missing then you can use

Window -> Appearance -> Show Toolbar

Answer (score -1):

Don't modified BuildConfig.java file,that file is generate by android sdk.

You can download android Tutorial  video help youself improve.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately, downloading a tutorial is exactly what I'm trying to do... but my eclipse doesn't match the tutorial.

Comment: you can download elipse ,then install plugins of eclipse adt or download ADT from [link]http://developer.android.com ,The key is not Eclipse version....